# Click is not working with react-html-parse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Click is not working with react-html-parse. OnClick event is not working while generating HTML from looping

```
const genRateRows = () => {
    let Data = ``;
    Object.keys(getProjList).map((oneKey, i) => {
        Data += `<div key={i}>
        <div>${oneKey}</div>`;

        Object.keys(getProjList[oneKey]).forEach((val, j) => {
            let tempObj = Object.values(getProjList[oneKey][val])[0];
            Data += ` <div className="projectCapsule d-flex" key=${j}>
                      <Col className="projectNameCapsule col-md-11">
                        <h5>${tempObj.talentName}</h5>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="seeDetailsCapsule">
                        <button onClick={alert("ok")}>
                        See Details
                        </button>
                      </Col>
                  </div>`;
        });
        Data += `</div>`;
    });

    return parse(Data);
};
```

Comment: What's the point in using an HTML parser here? Why not just create regular JSX?

Comment: @Phil tried but the second loop not showing data on the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant the [react-html-parser](https://github.com/peternewnham/react-html-parser) package, that is for generating JSX elements from regular HTML with the sole purpose of avoiding `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Since your syntax is already JSX, you don't need a parser

```jsx
const genRateRows = () =>
  Object.entries(getProjList).map(([projKey, proj]) => (
    <div key={projKey}>
      <div>{projKey}</div>
      {Object.entries(proj).map(([key, val]) => (
        <div className="projectCapsule d-flex" key={key}>
          <Col className="projectNameCapsule col-md-11">
            <h5>{val[0]?.talentName}</h5>
          </Col>
          <Col className="seeDetailsCapsule">
            <button onClick={() => alert("ok")}>See Details</button>
          </Col>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
```

Note that the `onClick` property for the button is now a function.

[image: Edit priceless-sun-z2zb49]

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
   <button ${ onClick={alert("ok")} }>
```

```js
            Data += ` <div className="projectCapsule d-flex" key=${j}>
                      <Col className="projectNameCapsule col-md-11">
                        <h5>${tempObj.talentName}</h5>
                      </Col>
                      <Col className="seeDetailsCapsule">
                        <button ${ onClick={alert("ok")} }> <-- Do this 
                        See Details
                        </button>
                      </Col>
                  </div>`;
```

Comment: it is not working. Getting error